# Get informations from .pkgx

Tags: powershell, package, sccm

I have tried the prestage content way to get packages for some of my new distribution point and I was wondering if it was any possibility to get the revision version of the .pkgx application created.
In that way, I will be able to see if my .pkgx have to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a .ini file and save the information you get while creating the .pkgx application (like the revision).
In that case, you'll be able to test the revision and "update" it(delete the .pkgx and create a new one).